# Restlet + jetty + https returns malformed response when http is requested

Tags: java, http, https, jetty, restlet

I have configured my restlet server to use https over the jetty http server.
The configuration is very simple:

```
  boolean https = c.getBoolean(CfgKeyNames.HTTPS, true);
  Protocol protocol = https ? Protocol.HTTPS : Protocol.HTTP;

  Component component = new Component();

  ServerList servers = component.getServers();
  for (Integer port : ports) {
    Server server = servers.add(protocol, port);
    if (https) {
      Series<Parameter> parameters = server.getContext().getParameters();
      parameters.add("sslContextFactory", PkixSslContextFactory.class.getName());
      parameters.add("keystorePath", Utils.getAbsolutePath(c, CfgKeyNames.KEYSTORE_PATH, "conf", "keystore.jks"));
      parameters.add("keystorePassword", c.getProperty(CfgKeyNames.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD));
      parameters.add("keyPassword", c.getProperty(CfgKeyNames.KEY_PASSWORD));
      parameters.add("keystoreType", c.getProperty(CfgKeyNames.KEYSTORE_TYPE, "jks"));
    }
  }
```

And it works fine. Except that when an http request is sent it returns nothing at all. Running fiddler reports the following response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 This buggy server did not return headers
```

(The response was generated by Fiddler.)

Anyway, how do I troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks.

**P.S.**

I am using Restlet 2.0.14 (it comes with Jetty 7.1)

**EDIT**

I have captured the traffic using WireShark. The complete dump as text is available here - http://pastebin.com/Yw80qvcT

The filter I used is `tcp.port == 11111 && ip.addr == 184.73.151.24` where the server runs on an AWS machine in the amazon cloud on port 11111.

**EDIT2**

Here is the binary capture file - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30319655/gl.pcap
This time the port is 443.

Comment: Can you get a pure capture with wireshark?

Comment: Done - http://pastebin.com/Yw80qvcT

Comment: Done in the binary format - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30319655/gl.pcap